# How to Verify Java Deployment Configuration is Working in Uninstalled JRE

Tags: security, java, deployment

I am deploying a Java application that uses a JRE included in the application directory.  The JRE is not installed on the host machine, but only used to run my application.  I have a custom "<JRE_DIR>/lib/deployment.config" file, specifying the path to a custom deployment.properties file.  These files are described in the [documentation for Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html).

Is there any way I can verify that my deployment.config/deployment.properties files are being used by Java?  If Java were installed, is there some way to do the same without using the Java Control Panel?

Comment: This seems more like a Java programming question ... you should be able to check the path to the loaded `deployment.properties` file at runtime.

Comment: @DavidPostill I copied a slightly modified version of this question to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360401/how-to-verify-java-deployment-configuration-is-working).  I'll wait to delete this until I verify the StackOverflow users don't tell me this question is better suited here on SuperUser.  Unfortunately, the best forum to host this question is somewhat dependent on the answer.